# Passing colours as arguments

Tags: color

I wanted to include a colour to an environment argument in the forms

```
{RGB}{249,104,21}
{rgb}{0.98,41.0,0.08}
{rgb/cmyk}{0.98,41.0,0.08/0.0,0.58,92.0,0.02}
```

Things are not going well with the the following document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{wvPz}{O{orange}mmo}
     {%
       \medskip%
       \IfNoValueTF {#4}
           {%
              \noindent #2 \ #3 \hspace{0.5cm}%
           }%
         {%
            \noindent #2 \ #3 \ (#4)%
            \par\smallskip
         }%
       \color{#1}%
    }%
  {%
     \par
     \medskip%
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{wvPz}[{RGB}{249,104,21}]{aa}{bb}[cc]
  C is a field. R is a subfield of C, and the degree of C as an
  extension field of R is 2. Furthec, C is not an ordered field.
\end{wvPz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I assumed this was you, why a new account every day?

Comment: totally unrelated to your definition, you have the wrong syntax for color you want `\color[rgb]{0.98,41.0,0.08}`  with `[]`   so `\color#1`  and `[[RGB]{249,104,21}]` if you really want to support that syntax

Comment: you don't need any of those `%` at ends of lines as you have ExplSyntaxOn (unless you _like_ adding `%`)

Comment: better to have two optional arguments (as they are not independent) then `\begin{wvPz}[RGB][249,104,21]` and `\begin{wvPz}[red]`  would both work.

Comment: by the way. in your earlier questions in yesterday's account `#2 \ #3` would make two word spaces between `#2` and `#3` but here in L3 code it makes half that space as the first space is just ignored white space in L3 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The model argument to `\color` is optional, so in `[]`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{wvPz}{O{orange}ommo}
     {
       \medskip
       \noindent #3 \ #4
       \IfNoValueTF {#5}
           {
             \hspace{0.5cm}
           }
         {
            \ (#5)
            \par\smallskip
         }
       \IfNoValueTF{#2}
          {\color{#1}}
          {\color[#1]{#2}}
    }
  {
     \par
     \medskip
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{wvPz}{aa}{bb}[cc]
  Default
\end{wvPz}

\begin{wvPz}[RGB][249,104,21]{aa}{bb}[cc]
  RGB 249,104,21
\end{wvPz}


\begin{wvPz}[RGB][104,249,21]{aa}{bb}[cc]
  RGB 104,249,21
\end{wvPz}


\begin{wvPz}[blue]{aa}{bb}[cc]
  Blue
\end{wvPz}

\end{document}
```